# openssl_cipher_iv_length workaround

Tags: encryption, openssl, php-5.3

I need to implement the openssl_cipher_iv_length() functionality on PHP version 5.3 where this function is not supported.

Would anybody be able to explain a way in which I can do this using PHP 5.3 friendly functionality only?

Comment: If your encryption algorithm (cipher method) is always the same, the result of this function should be always the same as well. Which cipher method are you using?

Comment: They are using AES, which I understand has 128 bit blocks. Would this then be the result of that function?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are always using AES as written in the comment)

For most of common AES cipher modes (CBC,CFB,ECB,OFB) the IV length should be 128 bits = 16 bytes, regardless of the key length (the 128/192/256 number in the name of cipher method).

As the [openssl_cipher_iv_length()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php) function returns the IV length [in bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php#116307), your implementation should return a constant value of `16`.

Good luck!